# Glitch in profile page when not logged in

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

Profile page has this section at the bottom:

[image: 1]

When I *am* logged in, clicking on All/Questions/Answers or Votes/Newest will filter/sort accordingly, and the orange highlight (colour may vary according to site) will shift to show the currently selected item.

The bug manifests itself when I am *not* logged in. In this case, clicking on Questions or Answers or Newest will successfully filter/sort, but the highlight will momentarily move to the selected item and then go back to the defaults, i.e. All and Votes. Now since the highlighted item cannot be selected again, this means if I filter/sort using any of the other options, I cannot show All Posts and Posts sorted by Votes again.

In short, while *not* logged in once Questions/Answers/Newest have been selected, one cannot select All/Votes again since the highlighting is broken.

Bug confirmed on many SE sites (must affect all since it's common code). Checked with Firefox (Windows) and Chrome (Android).

Comment: This happens because when you make a selection (e.g. clicking "Answers" or "Questions") the system store this selection server side, associated with your profile data, then it "remember" the selection permanently. When not logged in, there is no profile data to associate the selection with, so it always gets back to the default.

Answer (score 5):

User preferences are stored in the backend for the user. If you log out, we can't retrieve those preferences and you get the defaults.

We do that so your preferences are the same, whatever browser and device you log in with.

I have made a change so anonymous users can select from both options individually (but this is only till the page is refreshed). The behaviour is identical to all other sorts/filters on the user pages.

Comment: This is a bad user experience. Major part of the visits are from anonymous visitors and such UI gives unprofessional feeling. (nothing personal of course! :))

Comment: You can't use cookies or something for logged out users? Anyway, forget about saving the settings. On that page at least we should be able to select all the options, right? Like I said though, this is not possible. Once you have selected anything other than the defaults of All and Votes, you cannot select either of these two options again. Surely that needs to be fixed?

Comment: @Sha - guess I did't see the forest for the trees (didn't quite understand what the bug report was about)... fixed now.

Comment: Thanks @Oded, I noticed and reversed my vote (yeah, it was me who dared to downvote :)) - great people are not afraid to admit even small mistakes, so big kudos to you!